# Get parameters from hex string with defined lengths in php

Tags: php, hex

How to get the 7 variables from this string `"c0dbdc000081aa02000000000001c0"`, defining lengths for each one, some times it comes with voids in Zeros.

Definition to get the data from string:

```
0xc0->[SLIP Start char:C0]
0xdb,0xdc[C0]->Flag|Version:c,0
0x00->Reserved:0
0x00,0x81->Packet length:129
0xaa,0x02->Packet command:AA02[hex]
0x00,0x00->CRC check:0[hex]
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01->Serial number:1
0xc0->[SLIP End char:C0]
```

Example: this are 3 strings with the same data, but 2 of them are shorter in the "Packet length" value, they dont have the 2 leading zeros. (added some spacing to show the missing zeros)

```
"c0000000  9aaa02000000000029c0"
"c0000000  85aa0200000000000ac0"
"c0dbdc000081aa02000000000001c0"
```

The code i have works with the last one, but the first ones will get messed up because of missing Zeros. Any ideas on how to manage this?

```
$inputSample = "C0DBDC000081AA02000000000001C0";
$header = array(
    "start" => 2,
    "flagVersion" => 4,
    "reserved" => 2,
    "packetLenght" => 4,
    "packetCommand" => 4,
    "CRCcheck" => 4,
    "serialNumber" => 8,
    "end" => 2
);
print_r(ParseIrregularString($inputSample, $header));

function ParseIrregularString($string, $lengths) {
    $parts = array();

    foreach ($lengths as $StringKey => $position) {
        $parts[$StringKey] = substr($string, 0, $position);
        $string = substr($string, $position);
    }

    return $parts;
}
```

Good Result "C0DBDC000081AA02000000000001C0"

```
Array
(
    [start] => C0
    [flagVersion] => DBDC
    [reserved] => 00
    [packetLenght] => 0081
    [packetCommand] => AA02
    [CRCcheck] => 0000
    [serialNumber] => 00000001,
    [end] => C0
)
```

Bad Result "c00000009aaa02000000000029c0"

```
Array
(
    [start] => c0
    [flagVersion] => 0000
    [reserved] => 00
    [packetLenght] => 9aaa
    [packetCommand] => 0200
    [CRCcheck] => 0000
    [serialNumber] => 000029c0
    [end] => 
)
```

Comment: You can check the length of the string and compare it with the total length in your `header` array.  If the length is less then raise an error.  The program cannot guess what is missing from where, you have to tell it what is missing.

Comment: Are the missing zeroes always at the same place in the string? If not, how can you possibly know where they belong?

Comment: @ymas very good idea, to check the length of the string, the only problem is as Barmar is asking, i dont know if those ones are going to be the ones missing in all scenarios. I will try your approach, its all i have at the moment.

Comment: If you can control how the strings are made then perhaps you can pad the results to ensure they conform to the definitions in `header`.  If a third party is responsible for the strings then perhaps you can ask them to ensure their output is consistent.